# Docker exits immediately after run. However, Kitematic runs without issue

Tags: docker, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have been trying to get the Prestashop 1.6.1.9 image up and running via the CLI. If I try to execute a run command Docker will create the container but then it exits immediately. Even when I try and start the container that was just created it still exits immediately. When I go over to Kitematic it sees the newly created container and will start it up without issue if I tell it to. When I run `docker ps -a` after using the CLI to run the image I can see the container and it says `Exited (0)` and when I run it with Kitematic it says it's running. I'm new to Docker but this isn't making any sense to me. Any help would be much appreciated. Also, I installed Docker for Mac straight from their website as was suggested to do so.

EX: `docker run -dit --name prestashop-container-name -p 8080:80  prestashop/prestashop:1.6.1.9 -v ~/Desktop/Development/code-challenge/modules:/var/www/html/modules`

Comment: docker logs?     -d conflicts with -it.     Try running it interactively without the -dit option.

Comment: I ran the following: docker logs <container id> These are the results: 
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Sep 15 2016 20:44:43

Comment: Also, when I run without -dit the exact same thing happens.

Comment: Should I just uninstall and reinstall Docker?

Comment: Try removing the map, and apparently the official docs mix -d and -it.  So dunno about that...

docker run -ti --name some-prestashop -p 8080:80 -d prestashop/prestashop:1.6.1.9

Comment: Hmmm, that works! So the question is, why can't I declare a volume mapping in the run command? I'll try moving it towards the beginning and maybe that will work? I'll see.

Comment: You can.   But you are doing something wrong.   Could be permissions, syntax, mapping over something.

Comment: That's the only thing different that I did was move the mapping before the port exposing and it works like a charm. I went ahead and answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the placement of the volume mapping was the issue. I ran the following and it works like a charm.

`docker run -ti --name some-prestashop -v ~/Desktop/Development/code-challenge/modules:/var/www/html/modules -p 8080:80 -d prestashop/prestashop:1.6.1.9`